# Loads of 502 when using Unicorn + Nginx at scale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

We recently started getting a lot of 502s as we gained more traffic. We're using Rails + Nginx + Unicorn. I looked at the logs and I see a lot of these:

```
2014/04/21 07:38:38 [error] 883#0: *99265 connect() to unix:/home/app/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream
```

I'm not sure what to do at this point; any idea as to why this is happening? The app works 70% of the time.

Comment: Try adding up to your worker_processes in config/unicorn.rb. Default is 4, how many have you?

Comment: once you share the full configuration you'll get a reply quicker